# How to take a number from a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, currency

How can I take the number (**20** in the following example) in this string?

```
string = """<option value="full_review">Detailed review (Up to $20.00)</option>"""
```

I used

```
detailint = re.findall("""value="full_review">Detailed review (Up to $(.*))</option>""", bidsrc)
```

But it doesn't return me a sweat! Any tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `bidsrc = string`, you need to escape both the `$` and the `()` since they have a special meaning to the regex compiler. You'll also want to use `.*?`, or better `[\d.]+`, to match the actual amount.

```
r"""value="full_review">Detailed review \(Up to \$([\d.]+)\)</option>"""
```

Comment: Thanks for remembering me for escaping the special chars! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Detailed review (Up to $20.00)"
>>> re.findall("(\d+)\.",s)
['20']
```

I'm sure you've already checked, but the python docs on the [subject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is very helpful. Also look into the special characters that python uses, like `$`, `(`, and `)`.

To explain in more detail, in the regex above, `(\d+)` is the capturing group which captures 1 or more digits before a period (here, escaped as `\.`). that's why it matches `20` and not `00`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that '$' has a special meaning in regular expressions, so as '.', '(', ')', '*' and many others. You have to escape (eg. '\$') them if you don't want them to be processed specially

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
string = '<option value="full_review">Detailed review (Up to $20.00)</option>'
finded = re.findall("""value="full_review">Detailed review \(Up to \$([\d.].*)\)</option>""",string)
print finded
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `(`, `)` and `$` are special characters in regex paterns, you need to escape them with `\` in your pattern as following:

```
detailint = re.findall("""value="full_review">Detailed review \(Up to \$(.*)\)</option>""", bidsrc)
```

Another thing is using `.*` is not the best choice, since it will capture any character. It's much better to use `[\d]+` instead, which will capture at least one number (`*` is 0 or more, `+` is 1 or more; `\d` means any numeric character, and `[]` is character set):

```
detailint = re.findall("""value="full_review">Detailed review \(Up to \$([\d]+)\)</option>""", bidsrc)
```

Read more on python re library on: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "Detailed review (Up to $20.00)"
 re.findall("\$\d+\.\d+",s)[0][1:]
```

Gives you 20.00 (includes decimal as well)